# Compute the value of $\lim \int_0^1 f_n(x) \sin (nx)dx.$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits

> Let $\{f_n(x)\}$ be a sequence in $L^2[0,1]$ and $\lim f_n=f$ almost everywhere, where $f(x)\in L^2[0,1]$. Then find
> $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_0^1 f_n(x)\sin (nx)dx.$$

By Riemann-Lebesgue lemma, we can conclude that $$\lim \int_0^1 f(x)\sin(nx)dx=0.$$
But how to compute it for $f_n(x)$?

Answer (score 5):

The limit need not exist. For example if $f_n(x)=n^{2} \chi_{(0,\frac  1n)}$ and $f=0$ then $f_n \to f$ at every point but the given integral tends to $\infty$.

[$\int_0^{1}f_n(x) \sin (nx)dx=n\int_0^{1} \sin y dy=n(1-\cos 1)$ by the substitution $y=nx$].

Comment: Thanks sir, if we consider $f_n\leq f$, then does the limit exist ?

Comment: @Himadri If $|f_n| \leq |f|$ a.e then $\int |f_n(x)-f(x)|dx \to 0$ by DCT and using this and Riemann Lebesgue Lemma for $f$ it follows that $\int f_n(x) \sin (nx) \to 0$.